# How to Install IBM BPM 8.5.6 silently on Linux

Tags: linux, installation, business-process-management, silent-installer, ibm-bpm

I am asked to install IBM Business Process Manager (BPM) 8.5.6 on a Linux box in a silent mode, meaning no GUI and only through command line and response files. 
a) Do i need to install the Installation Manager first?
b) All the Linux pre requisites setup are done
c) Do I need to install Websphere Application Server (WAS) before installing BPM?
d) Please help me to setup IBM BPM using step by step guide. (installation and BPMConfig)
Note: I tried to look at IBM info center. Those instructions are confusing with lot of Database related information. We have a dedicated SQL server DBA to setup the Database for us.

Thanks,
Kumar.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the IBM Info Centre, you need to have Installation Manager and WAS ND installed before installing the BPM.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFTDH_8.5.5/com.ibm.wbpm.imuc.sbpm.doc/topics/inst_sil_cmd_lin.html?lang=en)

You could try the [BPM Interactive Installation and Configuration Guide](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFTDH_8.5.5/com.ibm.wbpm.imuc.doc/topics/bpm_roadmap_form.html?lang=en) to create the custom instructions for your installation and configuration.

Comment: Thanks Alvin,Kevin. I think I will be good with this information.

Answer (score 0):

There are Redbooks by IBM on that topic: http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg248175.html

With this resource we were able to install several instances of IBM BPM, it contains technical background (Installation Manager, WAS, Cluster, Nodes, Deployment Manager...) you need to know to set up your environment and leads you to a result step-by-step. It won't get any simpler than this.